# How to surface images above nav bar CSS and HTML

Tags: php, html, css

here is my code i was just wondering how i can bring that image above the nav bar! 
    http://jsfiddle.net/Xb2UT/640/

apbook

```
<body>
    <div id="logo00">
    <img src="http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/de/ca/decadd7edb6b1014ca0cb7a1afcb8ea3.png">
    </div>
    <header id="header">
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul id="ulnav">
                <li><a id="test11" href="#two">Software</a></li>
                <li><a id="test21" href="#three">Store</a></li>
                <li><a id="test31" href="about">About</a></li>
                <li><a id="test31" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a id="test31" href="careers">Career Opportunities</a></li>
                <li><a id="test31" href="support">Support</a></li>
                <div id="gay">
                    <li><button id="login-button">Login</button></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Why you have z-index on `#header`. Remove it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? And plus why would it matter that wouldnt fix anything.

Comment: Remove `z-index:10000;` from your `#header`. Or lower it to `9999` and give `#logo00 { z-index:10000; }`.

Comment: @divy3993 i tried that and it didnt work )= if i remove the z-index from header the image comes above but the nav no longer follows you as you scroll down the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean move the image in front of the header change the z-index on #header. If you mean move the image on top of the header increase the #header top value.

Comment: When i remove the z-index from #header the nav no longer follows you as you scroll down the page.